# Looking for a WP theme or other popular framework for building a dashboard

Tags: web-apps, wordpress, dashboard

Ok what I need to do is setup a website dashboard where the end users are sales people for our company.  The dashboard would allow them to communicate with corporate, reorder product, communicate internally with other distributors (via the website), ans see their sales numbers.  The "front page" would just be a simple login landing page, and the main content would be the dashboard itself per the user that's logged in.

Here is an example of what the dashboard might look like:

[image]

I would prefer to work with a framework like wordpress as it's so widely used and so robust. However I'll work with any framework so long as it looks good.  But I am looking for a theme or something I can buy and modify as opposed to building the entire site from scratch.